# bit-shift operation in accelerometer code

Tags: arduino, bit-manipulation, accelerometer, microcontroller, bit-shift

I'm programming my Arduino micro controller and I found some code for accepting accelerometer sensor data for later use. I can understand all but the following code. I'd like to have some intuition as to what is happening but after all my searching and reading I can't wrap my head around what is going on and truly understand.

I have taken a class in C++ and we did very little with bitwise operations or bit shifting or whatever you'd like to call it. Let me try to explain what I think I understand and you can correct me where it is needed.

So:

1. I think we are storing a value in x, pretty sure in fact.
2. It appears that the data in array "buff", slot number 1, is being set to the datatype of integer.
3. The value in slot 1 is being bit shifted 8 places to the left.(does this point to buff slot 0?)

This new value is being compared to the data in buff slot 0 and if either bits are true then the bit in the data stored in x will also be true so, 0 and 1 = 1, 0 and 0 = 0 and 1 and 0 = 1 in the end stored value.

The code does this for all three axis: x, y, z but I'm not sure why...I need help. I want full understanding before I progress.

```
//each axis reading comes in 10 bit resolution, ie 2 bytes.  
// Least Significant Byte first!!
//thus we are converting both bytes in to one int
x = (((int)buff[1]) << 8) | buff[0];   
y = (((int)buff[3]) << 8) | buff[2];
z = (((int)buff[5]) << 8) | buff[4];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is being used to convert the raw accelerometer data (in an array of 6 bytes) into three 10-bit integer values.  As the comment says, the data is LSB first. That is:

```
buff[0] // least significant 8 bits of x data
buff[1] // most significant 2 bits of x data 
buff[2] // least significant 8 bits of y data
buff[3] // most significant 2 bits of y data 
buff[4] // least significant 8 bits of z data
buff[5] // most significant 2 bits of z data
```

It's using bitwise operators two put the two parts together into a single variable.  The `(int)` typecasts are unnecessary and (IMHO) confusing.  This simplified expression:

```
x = (buff[1] << 8) | buff[0];
```

Takes the data in `buff[1]`, and shifts it left 8 bits, and then puts the 8 bits from `buff[0]` in the space so created.  Let's label the 10 bits `a` through `j` for example's sake:

```
buff[0] = cdefghij
buff[1] = 000000ab
```

Then:

```
buff[1] << 8 = ab00000000
```

And:

```
buff[1] << 8 | buff[0] = abcdefghij
```

Comment: Thank you! I've spent days reading about this stuff and you and the rest of the community brought me my eureka moment in less than 15 minutes! Your step by step explanation made it much easier to understand!

Comment: The incoming data (buff) is also two's complement, and it seems like the Arduino microprocessor will keep the sign when assigning the bits to `x` `y` `z`, which are floats in my version. It's quite confusing.

Comment: @mrmagooey, why wouldn't you want to keep the sign?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I do want the sign and the operation that occurs is the desired one, it was just another part of the above code that was confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

> The value in slot 1 is being bit shifted 8 places to the left.(does this point to buff slot 0?)

Nah. Bitwise operators ain't pointer arithmetic, don't confuse the two. Shifting by `N` places to the left is (roughly) equivalent with multiplying by 2 to the `N`th power (except some corner cases in C, but let's not talk about those yet).

> This new value is being compared to the data in buff slot 0 and if either bits are true then the bit in the data stored in x will also be true

No. `|` is not the logical OR operator (that would be `||`) but the bitwise OR one. All the code does is combining the two bytes in `buff[0]` and `buff[1]` into a single 2-byte integer, where `buff[1]` denotes the MSB of the number.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can we go in depth more? How are the bits actually combined? If we take the value in buff N and shift by 8 and how you said, multiplying by 2 to the 8th power, how does that combine? If I may guess....are we starting off with 16 bit places, or 2 bytes, and moving the data in the first eight bits to the left and replacing the zeros put in by the bit shift, with the data in buff slot 0? Also, would you explain MSB? I know it stands for most significant byte but that's the extent of my knowledge. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user2701295 Your guess seems correct at first glance. Most significant byte: the byte that has the most "weight" in (which contributes to the value of) the number.

Comment: So if we didn't care about accuracy we could throw away the LSB? like if we had a number that was in the tens of millions we wouldn't really care about what was in the hundreds place? Is that the idea?

Comment: @user2701295 Nah. The shift is always required. Grab paper & pen and work it out, you'll see why.

Answer (score 0):

The device result is in 6 bytes and the bytes need to be rearranged into 3 integers (having values that can only take up 10 bits at most).

So the first two bytes look like this:

```
00: xxxx xxxx <- binary value
01: ???? ??xx
```

The ??? part isn't part of the result because the xxx part comprise the 10 bits. I guess the hardware is built in such a way that the ??? part is all zero bits.

To get this into a single integer variable, we need all 8 of the low bits plus the upper-order 2 bits, shifted left by 8 position so they don't interfere with the low order 8 bits. The logical OR (| - vertical bar) will join those two parts into a single integer that looks like this:

```
x: ???? ??xx xxxx xxxx <- binary value of a single 16 bit integer
```

Actually it doesn't matter how big the 'int' is (in bits) as the remaining bits (beyond that 16) will be zero in this case.

Answer (score 0):

to expand and clarify the reply by Carl Norum.

The (int) typecast is required because the source is a byte. The bitshift is performed on the source datatype before the result is saved into X. Therefore it must be cast to at least 16 bits (an int) in order to bitshift 8 bits and retain all the data before the OR operation is executed and the result saved.

What the code is not telling you is if this should be an unsigned int or if there is a sign in the bit data. I'd expect -ve data is possible with an Accelerometer.